# White blank screen while adding or editing pages in wordpress

Tags: plugins, errors

I am not able to add or edit pages in wordpresss . When i go to the page edit option in wordpress a complete white blank screen is showing with the error message –

> (Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, function ‘wp_cache_set_posts_last_changed’ not found or
>   invalid function name in
>   /home/accounts/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 288)

All the things was working fine some days back . I have also tried to deactivate all the plugin to make sure it will not be due to any plugins but even after deactivating the plugins error is still showing.

I have already done lots of R & D to solve this issue but nothing works..

Comment: What about switching to a default theme keeping plugins disabled?

Comment: Did your system just get updated? Did someone change something? Tell us what you've tried and details of what is going on so we can help.